# Compress This Image - Compress This Image

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, spam

Okay, I'm about to start flagging these posts as spam. These two came in within minutes of each other:

- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138405/how-can-i-compress-reduce-the-image-using-javascript-in-visualforce-page
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138404/compressresize-image-without-losing-quality-using-javascript-in-visualforce

Here are some more:

- [how to compress the image size in visualforce page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137998/how-to-compress-the-image-size-in-visualforce-page)
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138079/how-to-compressreduce-the-image-size-using-visualforce
- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/138293/how-to-compress-or-reduce-the-image-size-using-visual-force-page-custom-functi

Five nearly identical posts within two days (just upon a cursory search). That doesn't seem like a coincidence. Why are we getting so many? Is flagging any more that come in as spam (at least while the trend continues) going too far?

Comment: I'm really confused by this also.  The one I pointed out the other day was a carbon copy (except for the dimensions), so the user had to have copied/pasted it from the original.  It was a deliberate attempt to either lower the quality of SFSE, or gain reputation points.  I'm not sure what else it could be?

Comment: Three of then from the same user...